# How to solve $x^{2/3}=4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

OK I know this sounds pretty stupid, but I am stuck on solving $x^{{2}/{3}}=4$. I rewrote it to $\sqrt[3]{x^2}=4$, but I don't know what to do next. Would the radical go away if I took the $\sqrt[3]{x^2}=4$ by the $3$rd power?

Then it would become $ x^6=64$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is still a hint

$$x^{2/3}=4$$
$$x^{2}=4^3=64$$

$$x=\pm8$$

I leave the rest to you!

Comment: omg thank you so much! I totally forgot!

Comment: so if the domain of this is [-1,27] then that means that -8 is not an answer, right?

Comment: @Amzoti I think -8 is part of the original solution???? since it's x^2

Comment: @Amzoti according to the calculator it's 4. and 4-4=0.

Comment: @Kaaagome: raising a negative number to a non-integral power is problematic in the reals.  Often it is not defined-you need to check your definition. Rational powers with an odd denominator can work, defied by the usual rules of exponents.

Answer (score 4):

You multiply both sides by $3$, getting $x^2=12$. Can you take it from here? Note that x^2/3 usually means $(x^2)/3$, not $x^{(2/3)}$

Comment: Down-vote should be reversed but till then +1 for compensation!

Comment: His question was edited and this isn't really an answer to the question

Comment: Before the edit, this was the only correct answer. +1 for you. OP (and other readers) should take this as a chastisement for poor notation. Order of operations is quite important and parentheses simply *must* be used if it is to be altered.

Comment: @Joao:  I answered before the edit. I think parentheses are *important* and this is a good example. Yes, it is likely that x^2/3 is intended as $x^{2/3}$, but the order of operations says otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if two positive quantities are equal, then you can raise them to the same power then the result will be equal.

So you cube both sides, to get $x^2=64$. There we get $\pm 8$ as solutions.

Clearly $x=8$ works ($8^{2/3}=4$).
On the other hand $(-8)^{2/3}=4$, so both $8$ and $-8$ are solutions.